# смена пользователя БД в django

Tags: база-данных, python-3.x, django, psycopg2

Впервые делаю django-проект с использованием PostgreSQL. В **settings.py** стоит:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': 'my_db',
        'USER': 'postgres',
```

Под этим юзером сервер стартует нормально и приложение открывается.

Если же я пытаюсь сменить значение **USER** на другого пользователя базы, который создан через **psql** с назначением всех прав, то сервер тоже стартует, но открывается debug-страница с сообщением:

*relation "django_session" does not exist*

Я прочитал некоторые рекомендации по этой ошибке, но команда

```
manage.py migrate
```

вызывает ошибку:

```
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: no schema has been selected to create in
LINE 1: CREATE TABLE "django_migrations" ("id" serial NOT NULL PRIMA...
```

Что я упускаю, переназначая юзера базы?

Comment: Ознакомьтесь https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/106057/error-no-schema-has-been-selected-to-create-in

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте сбросить миграции:

```
$ python manage.py migrate --fake имя_приложения zero
```

и мигрировать заново:

```
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```